# Showing the bijection of a function on the set of finite measures on a singleton

Tags: measure-theory

Let the set $E = \{a\}$ and $M(E) = \{\mu : \mathcal{B}(E) \to \mathbb{R}_+ : \mu$ finite measure$\}$.

Consider the function $f : M(E) \to \mathbb{R}_+$, defined as follows: 
$$f(\mu) = \mu(\{a\}).$$

I'm trying to show that this function is bijective.
Let $\mu, \nu \in M(E)$. 
$$f(\mu) = f(\nu) \iff \mu(\{a\}) = \nu(\{a\}) \iff (\mu - \nu)(\{a\}) = 0$$
Does $\mu = \nu$ result from here?

P.S. Can someone, please, give me a hint on how to demonstrate the surjection? Thank you!

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is a pretty small family. You should explicitly write it down to see that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: I don't know how to explicity $\mathcal{B}(E)$. Can you help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Start with the power set, $\mathscr{P}(E)$.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(E) = \{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$

Comment: Right. And a $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of the power set, satisfying a few conditions. What sets belong to every $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$?

Comment: $\emptyset$ and $X$. So, in our case, $\mathcal{B}(E) = \mathcal{P}(E)$.